# Android : Handling loading of data in fragments inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, observable

I have a Viewpager Activity with three fragments inside it. The activity has an filter with list of filter options. When activity is started the filter options list is fetched from the server and then the first filter is selected by default.

Fragment A ViewModel --> contains getXList(selectedFilterOption)
Fragment B ViewModel --> contains getYList(selectedFilterOption)
Fragment C ViewModel --> contains getZlist(selectedFilterOption)

So first filter options is fetched from the server and then adapter is set with the first selected option.
As its a viewpager it loads the first as well as second fragment i.e Fragment A and Fragment B will be loaded.
Now suppose, Fragment A is visible and fragment B is already loaded and filter option is changed. As different filter is selected the data needs to be updated in every fragment based on the selected filter.

This is handled like this :
As filter is changed , the current fragment's data is reloaded. OnPageChangeListener is implemented and on its change respective fragment's data is reloaded.
But due to this, everytime a tab is changed ,api call is triggered and data is fetched.
Second thing when the activity is loaded for first time it has already loaded the second fragment. So on tab change the second fragment's data is going to be loaded again which should not happen.This can be avoided with the checks but its going to be a mess.

Is there any better approach using observable pattern, the fragments data can be loaded after filter option is changed.

Answer (score 0):

> You can call api once the activity is started..After getting the data
>   you can create tab and through the viewpager you can pass the value
>   with doing filteration.. This will not call api again as long as you
>   stay in activity

Additionally if you want some observable you can see and use greenrobot event bus. It's pretty simple [eventbuslibrary](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)